# Issue with end of month date in DAYLIGHT SAVING TIME

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdatecomponents

End of month date gives diffrent date for ottawa canada time zone(Daylight saving).

I am trying to get end of the month date in Any time zone.

*Note : You can help me by changing time zone is setting (Mac or in iphone) ottawa canada.& paste code in playground*

```
extension Date {
    public func setTime(day: Int, month: Int,year:Int, timeZoneAbbrev: String = "UTC") -> Date {
        let x: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        let cal = Calendar.current
        var components = cal.dateComponents(x, from: self)

        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timeZoneAbbrev)
        components.hour = 0
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        components.day = day
        components.month = month
        components.year = year

        return cal.date(from: components) ?? self
    }
    func getMonthGapDate(month: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: month, to: self)!
    }

    func startOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
    }

    func endOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth())!
    }

}
let firstDayDate = Date().setTime(day: 1, month: 4, year: 2019)
let startDate = firstDayDate.getMonthGapDate(month: -1)
let endDate = firstDayDate.endOfMonth()
print(firstDayDate)
print(startDate)//Prints 2019-03-01 01:00:00 +0000(Ottawa - Canada time zone) Day light zone
print(endDate)// (This is issue)Prints 2019-03-31 04:00:00 +0000(Ottawa - Canada time zone) Day light zone//It should 2019 - 04 - 30
```

Comment: What output do you expect?  Ottawa summer time is GMT-4, so midnight in Ottawa is 04:00:00 in UTC, which is what is shown.

Comment: Would it help if the other functions in your extension used the same time zone as `setTime`?

Comment: If anything, your start date looks incorrect. Summer time was not in effect on March 1st, so it should be 05:00:00 since Ottawa is normally UTC-5

Comment: You probably want to use `components.timeZone=TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent` instead of UTC.  This will give you dates that have local midnight on the first and last days of the month.

Comment: If I use `autoupdatingCurrent` and set my timezone to Ottawa I get `2019-04-01 04:00:00 +0000
2019-03-01 05:00:00 +0000
2019-04-30 04:00:00 +0000` which is what I would expect

Comment: @Paulw11 what a catch. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using timezone abbreviations can be troublesome, although "UTC" is pretty safe.

However, I suspect that you should use `TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent` to ensure that you get dates with local midnight.

```
extension Date {
    public func setTime(day: Int, month: Int,year:Int) -> Date {
        let x: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        let cal = Calendar.current
        var components = cal.dateComponents(x, from: self)

        components.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
        components.hour = 0
        components.minute = 0
        components.second = 0
        components.day = day
        components.month = month
        components.year = year

        return cal.date(from: components) ?? self
    }
    func getMonthGapDate(month: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: month, to: self)!
    }

    func startOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)))!
    }

    func endOfMonth() -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1, day: -1), to: self.startOfMonth())!
    }

}
```

This gives me the following output:

> 2019-04-01 04:00:00 +0000
>
> 2019-03-01 05:00:00 +0000
>
> 2019-04-30 04:00:00 +0000

Note the +0000 - The dates are shown in UTC, but represent local midnight.

- At the start of March, Ottawa *is not* using summer time, so it is UTC-5
- At the end of March, Ottawa *is* using summer time, so it is UTC-4

Comment: can you tell on which countries zone get changes(Like on march in canada) ?

Comment: Each country has their own summer time rules and they can even change from year to year and from state to state (e.g. Australia has summer time in New South Wales, Victoria, Adelaide and Tasmania, but not Queensland or Western Australia. Sometimes the states with daylight savings time change on different dates).  Generally iOS is updated with new rules as changes are made and the `Calendar` class works it out for you.

Comment: You can also use the `daylightSavingTimeOffset()` function of `TimeZone` to determine if daylight savings is in effect for a given timezone on a given date